# Replace character in a String with HashMap

Tags: java, if-statement, hash, hashmap, equals

I have some idea to do this

I'm stuck on the if statement part, how can I make the comparison work?

The expected output for this example is: The string ones is use two test the map numberthree.

```
      String s = "The string 1s is use 2 test the map number3.";
 
        HashMap<Integer,String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put(1,"one");
        map.put(2,"two");
        map.put(3,"three");
  
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
        if (s.charAt(i) is equals to map.contains(1){
           s[i] = map.get(1);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert the character to the numeric value to check if it's a `key` in the `HashMap`. A better approach would be to use a `StringBuilder` since you are appending `String` in case it's found in the map:

```
String s = "The string 1s is use 2 test the map number3.";
HashMap<Integer,String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(1,"one");
map.put(2,"two");
map.put(3,"three");
        
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (char c : s.toCharArray()){
    if (Character.isDigit(c) && map.containsKey(Character.getNumericValue(c))){
        sb.append(map.get(Character.getNumericValue(c)));
    }else {
        sb.append(c);
    }
}

System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Another solution would be to store characters as the `key`:

```
String s = "The string 1s is use 2 test the map number3.";
HashMap<Character,String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put('1',"one");
map.put('2',"two");
map.put('3',"three");
                
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (char c : s.toCharArray()){
     if (map.containsKey(c)){
          sb.append(map.get(c));
     }else {
          sb.append(c);
     }
}

System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Output:

```
The string ones is use two test the map numberthree.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate the map and replace map key by its value in String.

```
for (Map.Entry<Integer,String> e: map.entrySet()) {
  s = s.replace(e.getKey().toString(), e.getValue());
}
```

I recommend you not iterate by character in string since if you want to replace two or more digit numbers like 22 you faced problem.

Demo:

```
String s = "The string 1s is use 2 test the map number3.";
HashMap<Integer,String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(1,"one");
map.put(2,"two");
map.put(3,"three");
for (Map.Entry<Integer,String> e: map.entrySet()) {
  s = s.replace(e.getKey().toString(), e.getValue());
}
System.out.println(s);
```

Output:

```
The string ones is use two test the map numberthree.
```